# why result of this Comparing is true

Tags: php

in this simple PHP code
 why php parser return true?

```
$text="51.406ABC917";
$floatval = floatval($text);//51.406
if($floatval==$text){
$result_compare = true;//php parser return true
}else{
$result_compare = false;
}
```

Comment: PHP looks to be casting the string to a float by parsing it up until it finds the first invalid character (for a float)

Comment: "If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically."

Comment: And another thing, never trust [float values](http://floating-point-gui.de/), especially in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), and [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Just check it.

> Type of Operand 1:string, resource or number
>   Type of Operand 2: string, resource or number
>   Translate strings and resources to numbers, usual math.

You could avoid convertion to float by adding typecasting to string.

```
if((string)$floatval==$text){
$result_compare = true;
}else{
$result_compare = false; //php parser return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

== will compare the data ,use === to compare data and datatype

Answer (score 0):

```
$floatval==$text
```

in the above comparison you are comparing a float value with a string

try with  **===** instead of **==**

Comment: if he did it, he will get a folse every time

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) . You should never compare floats for equality.

You need use the epsilon technique.

For example:

```
if (abs($forstFloat - $secondFloat) < epsilon) { 
   echo 'they are equal!!'
```

}

where `epsilon` is constant representing a very small number.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a == $b Equal TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
$a === $b Identical TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
```

Take this as example

```
<?php
var_dump(0 == "a"); // 0 == 0 -> true
var_dump("1" == "01"); // 1 == 1 -> true
var_dump("10" == "1e1"); // 10 == 10 -> true
var_dump(100 == "1e2"); // 100 == 100 -> true

switch ("a") {
case 0:
    echo "0";
    break;
case "a": // never reached because "a" is already matched with 0
    echo "a";
    break;
}
?>
```

[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    $text="51.406ABC917";
    $floatval = floatval($text);//51.406
    if($floatval===$text){
        $result_compare = 'true';//php parser return true
    }else{
        $result_compare = 'failed';
    }
```

LOGIC:

```
$a == $b    Equal   TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: if i change $text="51.406ABC917"; to $text="51.406917"; result is false but i want result to be true;

Comment: In that case use `if($floatval===$text){` to `if((string)$floatval===(String)$text){`

Answer (score 0):

1. Before comparison $text is converted to a float , with same result as floatval(),
   then you compare $floatval==$text, so result is pretty predictable - **TRUE**

   It's normal, when you compare variables from 2 different types, first them to be converted to closest same type.
2. I would suggest, when comparing float, use similar construct

   **if ( abs($floatval - floatval($text)) < 0.001 ) {..}**

   compare **difference** between 2 floats, instead them. Cause if u have 2 numbers, **45** and **45.00001** , php will think they differ.

What do you wanna accomplish ? Why you think this result is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$text="51.406ABC917";
$floatval = floatval($text);//51.406
if(strval($floatval)==$text){
    $result_compare = true;//php parser return true
}else{
    $result_compare = false;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If first part of string is numbers, it will be converted to numbers otherwise it will be zero (0). Yes, to compare value and type of variable, use `===` instead of `==`.

But in your case, you already convert string to float by `floatval($text);` then `===` same as `==`.

The problem is how php convert string to number by `floatval($text);`

This is how php convert string to numbers:

```
<?php
$foo = 1 + "10.5";                // $foo is float (11.5)
$foo = 1 + "-1.3e3";              // $foo is float (-1299)
$foo = 1 + "bob-1.3e3";           // $foo is integer (1)
$foo = 1 + "bob3";                // $foo is integer (1)
$foo = 1 + "10 Small Pigs";       // $foo is integer (11)
$foo = 4 + "10.2 Little Piggies"; // $foo is float (14.2)
$foo = "10.0 pigs " + 1;          // $foo is float (11)
$foo = "10.0 pigs " + 1.0;        // $foo is float (11)     
?>
```

Full document here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion